# Android ScaleAnimation not centre on screen

Tags: android, android-animation, scaleanimation

I'm running into a bit of a problem when pragmatically setting a Scale animation on an ImageView.
Basically I have and Image view set center H/V, but when I apply the animation it off sets it:(...Iv read about pivot x/y being set to 50% but it wont seem to work, any feed back would be great...Screen shot below

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.2f, 1, 1.2f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50,    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.2f, 1.4f, 1.2f, 1.4f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.4f, 1.0f, 1.4f, 1.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 50);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    image_view.startAnimation(set);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` or `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT` will do the work? example:

```
new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.2f, 1, 1.2f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f));
```

treat both `0.5f` like 50%, counting from left/top